# Failed to parse source map / unable to compile the code

Tags: eval, react-native-ui-kitten

I unable to complete my node code. I am getting lot of warnings. I set `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` and it is not working fine.

> WARNING in ./node_modules/@eva-design/eva/index.js
> Module Warning (from ./node_modules/@expo/webpack-config/node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> Failed to parse source map from 'C:\Users\Lenovo\drive\appd\node_modules\packages\eva\index.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Lenovo\drive\appd\node_modules\packages\eva\index.ts'

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I'm getting the same thing.  BTW, those are Failed warnings, you should be able to continue working.